# Rellenar List en Java

Tags: java, lista

Estoy comenzando a trabajar con List en Java, mi problema es el siguiente, estoy tratando de rellenar una lista de objetos, las clases son las siguientes:
Clase Cambios:

```
public class Cambios {

    private List<Cambio> cambios;

    public List<Cambio> getCambios() {
        return cambios;
    }

    public void setCambios(List<Cambio> cambios) {
        this.cambios = cambios;
    }
}
```

Clase Cambio:

```
public class Cambio {
    String idCard;
    String idList;


    public String getIdCard() {
        return idCard;
    }
    public void setIdCard(String idCard) {
        this.idCard = idCard;
    }
    public String getIdList() {
        return idList;
    }
    public void setIdList(String idList) {
        this.idList = idList;
    }
}
```

Estoy tratando de rellenarlas de la siguiente manera mediante los set, pero no se muy bien cómo funcionan las listas, gracias de ante mano

```
Cambios cambios;
Cambio cambio;
List <Cambio> cambioLista = null;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
   String idCard= "Valor de id" + i);
    cambioLista.get(i).setIdCard(idCard);
   cambios.setCambios(cambioLista);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear una lista de objetos necesitas primero inicializar la lista. En tu caso la lista es una propiedad de la clase `Cambios`, así que es necesario crear un objeto de dicha clase, instanciarlo y despues inicializar la lista:

```
Cambios cambios = new Cambios();
cambios.setCambios(new ArrayList<>()); // inicializamos lista
```

Para llenar la lista llamamos al metodo `add` y le pasamos un objeto del tipo del que esta declarada la lista. En tu caso la lista contendra objetos de la clase `Cambio`, así que necesitamos crear primero objetos de dicha clase y despues agregarlos a la lista:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   Cambio cambio = new Cambio();
   cambio.setIdCard("El idCard es: " + i); // asignamos idCard
   cambio.setIdList("El idList es: " + i); // asignamos idList
   cambios.getCambios().add(cambio); // agregamos objeto a la lista
}
```

Comment: cambios.add(cambio); es correcto? no se puede hacer un add a cambios

Comment: me falto tomar la lista del objeto `cambios`

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás usando es una interface, puedes usarla como variable de referencia o implementandola directamente en la clase y sobreescribir sus métodos pero nunca podrás tener una instancia de algún objeto de ese tipo.

Te recomiendo utilizar la clase [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/), te permitirá crear una lista de objectos del tipo definido dentro del modificar ArrayList`<E>`. Aquí está tu codigo modificado.

**Primera clase**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cambios {

    private ArrayList<Cambio> cambios;

    public ArrayList<Cambio> getCambios() {
        return cambios;
    }

    public void setCambios(ArrayList<Cambio> cambios) {
        this.cambios = cambios;
    }
}
```

**Segunda clase**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Cambios> listacambios = new ArrayList<Cambios>(); // Crea un objeto ArrayList

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

            listacambios.add(new Cambio()); // Crea un objeto de tipo Cambio y almacena una referencia dentro del ArrayList

        }

        Cambios cambios = new Cambios(); // Crea un objeto de tipo Cambios
        cambios.setCambios(listacambios); // Pasa como argumento del método una referencia al ArrayList

        ArrayList<Cambio> listacambios = cambios.getCambios(); // Crea una nueva referencia de tipo ArrayList y asignale el objeto ArrayList dentro de la clase cambios.

        String idCard;        

        for(int i=0;i<listacambios.size();i++) {

            idCard = "Valor de id: "+i;

            listacambios.get(i).setIdCard(idCard);

        }
    }
}
```

Existen formas de optimizar el código para no ser redudante, pero por motivos de comprensión para no ser tran drástico con las modificaciones lo hice de esta forma, te recomiendo estudiar sobre los for extendidos y revisar el API de la clase ArrayList para aprender más sobre sus métodos.